# Capture cell signal strength using react-native

Tags: android, ios, react-native

Is it possible to capture cell signal strength using react-native?

Can't seem to find any projects to facilitate what seems like a typical query. Is it even possible on the native level on ios/android?

Answer (score 1):

on iOS its not possible via documented APIs. With private APIs you might face app rejection. So  in principle Not possible. 
You can use [this](https://github.com/valexa/VAFieldTest) for getting signal strength.